# Blogger: How to include a Page with all the things that I +1'd (possibly through RSS feed)?

Tags: google-plus, rss, blogger

I'd like to create a new Page in Blogger that aggregates all of the pages that I have +1'd.

I'd like the feed that is generated in Google Plus `https://plus.google.com/u/0/<userID>/plusones` to display on the Page created in Blogger.

Some solutions:

- Just link out to the Google Plus plusones page.  *I would rather avoid this, as it will take the user away from the blog.*
- Create an RSS feed out of the plusones page.  *I like this idea, but unfortunately can't get it to work.  Tried some solutions from [this Google Forum Question](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFQQFjAA&url=http://productforums.google.com/d/topic/reader/cUmXHqglTG0&ei=OO68T7iaLMiMgwew-qGqDw&usg=AFQjCNEyCG6PTY6jQqe8w8Z6OF1DuO6xag) and from [this blog post](http://blog.luisfreitas.pt/2012/01/22/how-to-create-a-google-plus-rss-1/), but was unsuccessful.*
- Create some custom Javascript/AJAX.  *This would require a lot of extra work that can already be solved by the RSS Feed.  Plus, I don't think the plusones API has been made available yet.*

Has anyone gotten this to work or been able to successfully generate an RSS feed from the plusones page?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a json feed with Google+ API. Here is a sample request -

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/100089984211197410017/activities/public?alt=json&fields=id%2Citems(kind%2Cobject(attachments%2Furl%2Ccontent%2CoriginalContent)%2Ctitle%2Curl)&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Sample results -

```
{
 "id": "tag:google.com,2010:/plus/people/100089984211197410017/activities/public",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "plus#activity",
   "title": "Always have your stuff when you need it with @Dropbox. Sign up for free! http://db.tt/GzHFzuZ",
   "url": "https://plus.google.com/100089984211197410017/posts/BP9YtjFWTdJ"
  },
  {
   "kind": "plus#activity",
   "title": "500px for Android is here! The app doesnt have upload option. You can only view photos you or som...",
   "url": "https://plus.google.com/100089984211197410017/posts/BUfEM2wg3a2"
  },
  {
   "kind": "plus#activity",
   "title": "Reshared post from Mimi Round",
   "url": "https://plus.google.com/100089984211197410017/posts/NzSj1kBj7J8"
  },
  ...
 ]
}
```

You can find more details at [Google+ API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list).

Comment: Thanks Bibhas, but this is showing normal activity (`plus#activity`), which consists of posts, articles, videos, photos, blogs (that are shared publicly).  How can I specify to return only things that I have plusone'd?

Comment: The answer you gave is for activity on Google+ itself (so the +1's would be for +1's on posts). There doesn't seem to be an API/Feed available for just the Page +1 activity that happens on an account.

Comment: @Dez can you not filter by [activityID](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/get) ?